# JMeter - JSR223 Sampler missing character encoding

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, jmeter, jsr223

When I use JSR223 Sampler and print non English characters as `อักษรไทย`

I can't be seen in output, converted to `????????`

I see that the encoding isn't set to `UTF-8` in Sampler Result

```
SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: windows-1255
```

Can I set JSR223 Sampler output encoding to `UTF-8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's the problem of the destination you're printing this stuff to, if you use [`log` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) which prints an arbitrary line to [*jmeter.log* file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) you should normally see non-English characters

If you're writing non-ANSI text into a custom file to be on the safe side you could [explicitly define encoding](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#withWriter(java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) like:

```
new File("foo.txt").newOutputStream().withWriter("UTF-8") { writer ->
    writer.write('อักษรไทย')
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I put non english chars as is and Listener show it wrong by using windows-1255 encoding

Comment: Trying to print Thai letters using Hebrew encoding is not something you should be normally doing.

Comment: You are right, but how to change listener output encoding?

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to guess which listener you're talking about and what is your scenario. If you need further assistance share the minimal version of your Test Plan somehow and let us know the desired outcome

Comment: JSR223 Sampler with only `"อักษรไทย"` and View Results Tree to view Response Body

Comment: Make sure to set `file.encoding` property to `UTF-8`, it can be done either via *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) or you can do it by passing the property via [-D command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar ApacheJMeter.jar`. More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)